# How to run Python code using a specific Python environment in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I've started working on a large-scale Python program, and I'm using Visual Studio as my main IDE.

I have the entirety of Visual Studio's extensions for the use of Python, including Anaconda, which I used to create an environment from which I want to run my Python code.

Any ideas on how I can get that to happen?

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio Code?

Comment: @MingChu No, no - I mean Visual Studio.

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer was going into

```
View > Other Windows > Python Environments
```

and selecting the version of Python to work with.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019
[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019]